# How to express "When it comes to"?

Tags: grammar

So google translator seemly tells me that to express "When it comes to"  I should use the following structure (I tried finding it on google and this forum but could not find it)

> それは ... ことになると

For instance

> それは歩くことになると **"When it comes to walking"**

But since I don't trust google translator at all, I am asking, what is the right way to say that?

The sentence I am trying to make is the following **"When it comes to drinking everyday, it seems that Japanese people drink more than Brazilian people."**(refeering to the image that many people go to izakaya after work). My attempt:

> それは、毎日飲むことになると、日本人はブラジル人より、飲みそうだと思う

What do you think? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the “it” is dummy/hypothetical subject. I think you don’t have to translate it. Even If you omit “それは”, it makes sense. I think even in Portuguese ele è importante a practicar portuguese todos os dias. It is important to practice Portuguese every day.

Comment: I wonder why GT didn't adopt （歩く）となると.

Comment: @kimiTanaka "É importante praticar português todos os dias" really makes sense in portuguese, though I could see an equivalent for それは also, something like "That is, it is important to practice Portuguese every day", anyways. I did feel it sounded weird but, you never know lol that's why I nver trust GT, though at times it's the only place I can consult

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「それは ... ことになると」 sounds funny, particularly the 「それは」 part.  Looks like Google ***forcibly*** translated the word "it".

Most naturally, we would say:

・「～～に関{かん}して（言{い}えば/言うと）」

・「～～について言えば」

・「～～にかけては」

・「～～のことになると」

You could say:

> 「日{ひ}ごろの（アルコールの）飲{の}み方{かた}に関して言えば、日本人はブラジル人よりも飲むような気{き}がする。」

Your sentence, though, would be understood by nearly all native speakers if you just dropped 「それは」.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know most of these structures, it will be very useful

Comment: How about adding also the simple "N+と言えば"? If I remember correctly that's also a standard way to say "speaking of N" which in a way I think it could be quite similar to "when it comes to N".